# How to check if several variables are empty in Perl

Tags: perl, variables

I have a Perl script where variables must be initialized before the script can proceed. A lengthy `if`  statement where I check each variable is the obvious choice. But maybe there is a more elegant or concise way to check several variables.

**Edit:**
I don't need to check for "defined", they are always defined with an empty string, I need to check that all are non-empty.

Example:

```
my ($a, $b, $c) = ("", "", "");

# If-clauses for setting the variables here

if( !$a || !$b || !$c) {
  print "Init failed\n";
}
```

Comment: You'll probably get more/better answers if you provide an example of how you're currently doing it, including the appropriate reaction if one or more hasn't been initialized. (Throw an error? Set them to a default value? Etc.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am assuming that *empty* means the empty string, not just any false value. That is, if `0` or `"0"` are ever valid values post-initialization, the currently accepted answer will give you the wrong result:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my ($x, $y, $z) = ('0') x 3;
# my ($x, $y, $z) = ('') x 3;

for my $var ($x, $y, $z) {
    die "Not properly initialized\n" unless defined($var) and length $var;
}
```

Now, this is pretty useless as a validation, because, more than likely, you would like to know which variable was not properly initialized if this situation occurs.

You would be better served by keeping your configuration parameters in a hash so you can easily check which ones were properly initialized.

```
use strict; use warnings;

my %params = (
    x => 0,
    y => '',
    z => undef,
);

while ( my ($k, $v) = each %params ) {
    validate_nonempty($v)
        or die "'$k' was not properly initialized\n";
}

sub validate_nonempty {
    my ($v) = @_;
    defined($v) and length $v;
}
```

Or, if you want to list all that were not properly initialized:

```
my @invalid = grep is_not_initialized($params{$_}), keys %params;
die "Not properly initialized: @invalid\n" if @invalid;

sub is_not_initialized {
    my ($v) = @_;
    not ( defined($v) and length $v );
}
```

Comment: +1 for hash of params and catching the bug that everyone including OP had for treating "0" as uninitialized

Comment: In your middle code snippet I don't see that sub `validate_nonempty` being used. Does it need to be there?

Comment: @Matt Thank you for noticing that. Yes, it did need to be there ... I must have accidentally deleted something while fiddling with the post.

Answer (score 8):

What do you mean by "initialized"? Have values that are not "undef"?

For a small amount of values, the straightforward if check is IMHO the most readable/maintainable.

```
if (!$var1 || !$var2 || !$var3) {
    print "ERROR: Some are not defined!"; 
}
```

By the way, checking `!$var` is a possible bug in that "0" is false in Perl and thus a string initialized to "0" would fail this check. It's a lot better to use `$var eq ""`

Or better yet, space things out for >3 values

```
if    (!$var1          # Use this if your values are guarantee not to be "0"
    || $var2 eq ""     # This is a LOT better since !$var fails on "0" value
    || $var3 eq "") {

    print "ERROR: Some are not defined!"; 
}
```

If there are so many values to check that the above becomes hard to read (though with per-line check as in the second example, it doesn't really ever happen), **or if the values are stored in an array**, you can use grep to abstract away the checking:

```
# We use "length" check instead of "$_ eq ''" as per tchrist's comment below
if (grep { length } ($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, @more_args) ) {
    print "ERROR: Some are not defined!"; 
}
```

If you must know WHICH of the values are not defined, you can use for loop (left as an obvious excercise for the reader), or a map trick:

```
my $i = -1; # we will be pre-incrementing
if (my @undefined_indexes = map { $i++; $_ ? () : $i }
                                ($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, @more_args) ) {

    print "ERROR: Value # $_ not defined!\n" foreach @undefined_indexes; 
}
```

Comment: I’m of the opinion that if you find yourself explicitly writing `$_`, you may be doing something suboptimally in Perl.  I especially loathe `$_ =~ /foo/`.  I often write `grep { length } @list`, `map { hex } @list`, or `for (@list) {s/foo/bar/}`. Even `keys %h == grep { defined $h{$_} } keys %h` can be `values %h == grep { defined } values %h`. A closure expression is short enough to hold `$_`’s meaning of “it” in my head for `grep`,`map`,`first`,`all`,&c. Longer code with mixed access to `$this` and `$that` deserves having a name put to the abstraction: `$_` doesn’t really work for that.

Comment: @tchrist - good point. Given the clarification from the user that he is checking for `""` and not `undef`, `length` is a good choice - edited. How would you approach getting rid of `undef`s without using `$_` ?

Comment: `@list == grep { defined } @list` to determine whether they all are, or `@list = grep { defined } @list` to weed out those that aren’t.

Answer (score 8):

```
use List::MoreUtils 'all';
say 'Yes' if (all { defined } $var1, $var2, $var3);
```

Comment: +1 - I knew there was a MoreUtils way of doing that, but was too lazy at 4am to bother finding :)

Comment: I’m deeply conflicted about constantly turning to modules for things, perhaps especially to non-standard ones.  On the one hand, I don’t want people reïnventing wheels badly, but on the other, I wish they’d become fluent in basic Perl functionality, the stuff that’s already there in how the core language itself operates.

Answer (score 7):

```
use List::Util 'first';

if (defined first { $_ ne "" } $a, $b, $c) {
    warn "empty";
}
```

Comment: It looks weird, but it works and will save me from typing " || !" over and over again.

Comment: By *empty*, the OP probably means *empty string*, not *false*. The standard way to check that is `length` in Perl. Also, do not use `$a` and `$b` as they are package variables used by `sort`.

Comment: @Sinan: The OP declares `$a` and `$b` with `my`. These are not package variables. Thanks for the good point though.

Comment: this approach does not seem to be the most readable/maintainable (though it does deserve +1 from me on purely technical merits).

Comment: 'all' or 'any' from List::MoreUtils are even nicer.

Answer (score 3):

Your way is readable and easy to understand which means it's easy to maintain. Restating your boolean using [de Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
if (not($a and $b and $c)) {
   warn(qq(Not all variables are initialized!))
}
```

That way, you're not prefixing *not* in front of every variable, and it doesn't affect readability. You can use `List::Util` or `List::MoreUtils`, but they don't really add to the legibility.

As Sinan Ünür stated, if you put the variables in a hash, you could parse through the hash and then list which variables weren't initialized. This might be best if there are a lot of these variables, and the list keeps changing.

```
foreach my $variable qw(a b c d e f g h i j) {
    if (not $param{$variable}) {
        warn qq(You didn't define $variable\n);
    }
}
```

You can use `Getopts::Long` to put your parameter values inside a hash instead of separate variables. Plus, the latest versions of `Getopts::Long` can now operate on any array and not just `@ARGV`.